# Recommended API design with ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 3. I'm kind of new to it. I think I'm starting to get the hang of it. But there is something that I'm trying to do, that I think makes sense, but maybe I'm wrong.

I'm trying to create an API around Order objects in my database. In order to get all of the orders in the system, I was going to expose an API that looks like the following:

/orders/

In cases where I wanted to get a specific Order, I would simply append an ID. In other words, the URL would look like this:

/orders/12345

In an effort to accomplish this, I created the following controller:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Orders/
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string result = "list of orders";
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Orders/{orderID}
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        string result = "order:" + id;
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

In my AreaRegistration class, I have the following:

```
  public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
  {
    context.MapRoute(
      "OrderList",
      "{controller}/{action}",
        new { action = "Index", controller="Orders" }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
      "Order",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { action = "Index", controller = "Orders" }
    );
  }
```

When I attempted to access "/orders/", via the browser address bar, I get the JSON like I would expect. However, if I attempt to access "/orders/12345", I receive a 404. What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: what does your routing table look like?

Comment: I haven't done anything to it. Because this controller is in an Area, I wasn't sure where to setup the routing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also define proper routes in `global.asax` or use the default route which looks like `{controller}/{action}/{id}` where controller is defaulted to "Home", action is defaulted to "Index" and id is optional.

So `/orders` works because you have defined controller (orders), default action (Index) and missing id (which doesn't matter as it is optional)

But when you try `/orders/12345` then you have defined controller (orders), action (12345) and missing id

So to make this work with only the default route the request should be `/orders/index/12345`

edit: for registering area routes you should use AreaRegistration class

Comment: I concur 100% here +1, adding only that if you want a separate route simply add it above the default route and specify /orders/{id} instead.

Comment: this is what i was hinting at. +1 :)

Comment: I added the following to my AreaRegistration and I still get a 404 "            context.MapRoute(
  "Order",
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { action = "Index", controller="Orders" }
);

Comment: @MonoDeveloper but the second argument isn't what your desired url looks like... read this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with what you're saying. Are you saying I can NOT accomplish what I'm trying? I've included my AreaRegisration code in the question text above.

Comment: Try something like `context.MapRoute( "ViewOrder", "orders/{id}", new { action = "Index", controller="Orders" } );` You want the second argument string to *match* the url that you want to use. Or to think about it a different way, the framework is going try to match the incoming request path to any route that you have defined. If it can't match a route, then you get a 404.